# PHP calculation always round up

Tags: php, rounding, calculator, number-formatting, calculation

So, I want to calculate two variables and multiply them to have an automatic price-per-unit-calculation. Everything works but as soon as I start calculating something, the result turns rounded off.

An example:

14,94 * 100 should be 1495
But I get 1400.

Tried number_format, round, ceil, etc. ....nothing resolved the issue.

That's the code, I already have $weight and $price as the currect numbers, so this isn't the problem.

```
$gewicht_angabe = strip_tags ($weight);
$preis_angabe = strip_tags ($price);
$ergebnis = number_format((($preis_angabe * 100) / $gewicht_angabe), 2);
```

I have PHP 7.4 on MariaDB , is there maybe something I'm missing?

**EDIT:**

Problem has been solved by @maik-lowrey . This is the fixed code that does what I want:

```
$gewicht_angabe = strip_tags ($weight);
$preis_angabe = strip_tags ($price);
$preis_angabe = str_replace(',', '.', $preis_angabe);
$ergebnis = number_format((($preis_angabe * 100) / $gewicht_angabe), 2);
```

Comment: Why do you use `strip_tags()`? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump($gewicht_angabe, $preis_angabe);`

Comment: Note that if we test this claim with a simple `$a = 14.94; $b = 100; echo $a * $b;` we get `1494`, as it should be. So if that's not what's happening for you you're going to have to show a [mcve] so that others can see the same thing happening for the (heavily reduced) code that you're using. Just based on your text claims, this is not reproducible.

Comment: this is my first use-case, sorry, if I made some mistakes. I will add more details for future questions but for now my problem has been resolved by @maik-lowrey

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you want to calculate with a string. 14.95' is a string. what you need is a 14.95'. You can replace it, for example.

```
$a = "14,95";
$b = 100;
$a = str_replace(',', '.', $a);
echo $a * $b;
// 1495
```

Comment: That indeed helped, thank you so much! Nowbetween the second and third line a new line looks like this:

`$preis_angabe = str_replace(',', '.', $preis_angabe);`